# add php function to a string

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add this php function:

```
<?php _e("[:en]Read more[:cy]Darllen Mwy"); ?>
```

to this string:

```
$more = '<span class="excerpt-read-more"><a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '"><br />Read More &raquo;</a></span>';
```

The top php function about should replace the "Read More »" bit of the bottom string.

I'm rubbish at php and keep getting syntax errors or nothing at all.

Comment: Sorry, what? Do you mean you want to print the code of the PHP function in the link? Or print the result? Or have a click of the link call that PHP function? Or something else entirely? Please clarify exactly what you want the end result to be...

Comment: Elaborate on the translation.

Comment: You're already adding the output of functions into your string. You can't do it with another one?

Comment: was reading your other comments, have you checked the source to make sure that what is being returned by that function is not some html? Just getting ">>" seems to me like that function is outputting html. Try using `print_r(_e("[:en]Read more[:cy]Darllen Mwy"));` and then check the source to see what exactly is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly have no idea if this is even what you are asking, but:

```
$more = '<span class="excerpt-read-more"><a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '"><br />' . _e("[:en]Read more[:cy]Darllen Mqy") . ' &raquo;</a></span>';
```

Seems to be what you want..

Comment: What I want to end up with is the "Read more" link to appear in the different language depending on what language the site is being viewed in. I'm using qTranslate with WordPress and that function is used to determine that. I tried what was suggested and it just displays the >> not the Read more in any language.

Comment: Sounds as if your _e() function is not working properly, then. I have no experience with qTranslate so I can't be of much help here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
$more = '<span class="excerpt-read-more"><a class="more-link" href="'
        . get_permalink()
        . '" title="'
        . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' )
        . '"><br />'
        . _e("[:en]Read more[:cy]Darllen Mwy")
        . ' &raquo;</a></span>';
```

But to be honest, your question is not very clear about what you want, so that may not give you the result you're after...

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity.